# There are a number of state variables in a web page, Is making a database entry for each variable is the only way out?

Tags: database

Many Websites(say facebook) have many features active on their web pages. These features have many state variables associated with them, which are customizable as well. So, is storing the value of each variable in database the only way out? Or Is there some other method as well?
(Not specific to any particular language, database, framework etc).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much, yes.  If you're website is going to store information about/for its users then this needs to go in a database.  It could be written to a file (which is the same concept as a db just not as nice to work with), or kept in memory which means it will all disappear when the process running the website stops.

Is there a particular reason you don't want to use a database, or something you are trying to achieve that you think is incompatible with a database?

Comment: nothing like that, but I was just curious to know the latest industry practice, because to me it appears that even for some minor changes on the screen u need to create a field in the database and make an entry corresponding to that.Probably some other kind of database systems such as Cassandra might have some alternate ?

Comment: Your first sentence sums up our jobs. That is what we do - lots of really simple, repetitive tasks to create something complex & great. Another way to think about it is that screen changes only occur because we want to collect or display some new data. The data is not changing because we want the screen to look different. To me it sounds more meaningful that way. I'm not sure that something like Cassandra is designed to make changes easier, however there are tools (Object/Relation mappers) and frameworks (MVC.net, Ruby on Rails, etc) that are designed to make these changes easier to implement.